# kwargs in the Base Class Tuple in Python

Tags: python, generics, inheritance

I have noticed the snippet posed [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/85), which is:

```
class Iterable(Generic[T], extra=collections_abc.Iterable): # (*)
    pass

class Iterator(Iterable, extra=collections_abc.Iterator):  
    pass
```

Question 1: How does `extra=...` work in this snippet? Or more generally, when can we put a keyword argument when subclassing? What does it do?

Question 2: As is mentioned in the discussion in the hub, the first class (marked with `*`) is a generic class parametrized on the type variable `T`. However, I am looking for something like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class X(Generic[T]):
    a = T

class Y(X[int]):
    pass

Z = X[int]

print(Y.p) # gives "~T", but what I would like is "int"
print(Z.p) # also gives "~T"
```

In words, how to get a concrete subclass where the parameter `T` is fixed instead of the generic subclass with `T` undetermined? My first thoughts are something like these:

```
T = TypeVar(T)
class X(Generic[T]):
    p = T

class F(X[T], arg, **kwargs):  # as a functor with kwargs being the params? 

    # Do something to substitute T with arg
    '''
        This I suppose is incorrect and it is majorly 
    for this that I asked the first question.
    '''
    pass

# so that I can do
class Y(F, arg=P):
    pass
```

I looked into `type(name, bases, dict)` reference about dynamical class creation (even though the situation can be static) but I failed to find any specification on the `bases` argument about putting a tuple (kwargs) in the args.